# How to detect universal reference parameter type with std::is_same

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Have a look at these lines:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T&& param) {
    if (std::is_same<T, int>::value) {
        cout << "param is an int" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "param is not an int" << endl;
    }
    if (std::is_same<T, int&>::value) {
        cout << "param is an lvalue reference to int" << endl;
    }
    if (std::is_same<T, int&&>::value) {
        cout << "param is an rvalue reference to int" << endl;
    }
}
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    f(i);
    f(std::move(i));
    return 0;
}
```

The first function call `f(i)` yields:

```
param is not an int

param is an lvalue reference to int
```

which is what I expected, because as per the template argument deduction rules, `T` resolves to `T&`, resulting in `T&& &` which yields `T&` because of reference collapsing.

The second funtion call `f(std::move(i))` yields

```
param is an int
```

which is not what I expected. I'd have expected

> param is an rvalue reference to int

or at least

> param is not an int

Can someone explain why my expectations regarding the second function call are not met  ?

Comment: `T&&` for `int&&` : `T` -> `int`

Comment: You have universal reverence so `param` cannot be a value! When `T` is an `int`, `param` is a `int&&`.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void f(T&& param) {
    using raw_type = std::remove_reference_t<T>;
    if (std::is_same<decltype(param), raw_type>::value) {
        cout << "param is an int" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "param is not an int" << endl;
    }
    if (std::is_same<decltype(param), raw_type&>::value) {
        cout << "param is an lvalue reference to int" << endl;
    }
    if (std::is_same<decltype(param), raw_type&&>::value) {
        cout << "param is an rvalue reference to int" << endl;
    }
}
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    f(i);
    f(std::move(i));
    return 0;
}
```